# How does super() work in a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, super

I have a quick question regarding how super() is used in a constructor. I know the basics about how it will call a superclass but I recently looked at some code and don't understand how it is being used in this example. Here's the gist of the part that confuses me:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    String myString = null;

    public MyClass() {
        super();
    }

    public MyClass(String A) {
        super();
        myString = A;
    }

    public interfaceMethod {
        // this is the method from MyInterface
    }
}
```

I understand how the constructors are being used and all but I just don't see the point to the super() methods in them. Does it have to do with the interface that it's implementing? I thought super() was used if a class extends something? Am I missing some basic knowledge about java here? Any help for a noob would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `super()` refers to `java.lang.Object` 's default constructor, all object implicitly extends `Object`

Answer (score 1):

Any `java` class inherits from `java.lang.Object` by default implicitly, hence above code snippet will call the constructor of Object class (which currently does nothing).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Am I correct in assuming the super() here has nothing to do with the interface? Am I also correct in assuming getting rid of the super()'s in each constructor will really not have any impact on the code?

Comment: You are correct. The MyClass() constructor is a no-argument constructor. In fact it was not necessary to call super() at all since a no-arg constructor automatically calls super() as the first thing it does. The constructor body could have been empty. There's a good discussion of all this at http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076204/core-java/understanding-constructors.html

Answer (score 0):

In inheritance, when child class gets instantiated, the default(zero argument) constructor of base class gets invoked, regardless of presence of `super()` in child class constructor. However, if you want to invoke any other constructor of parent, you can call it using super(with arguments). In short, `Super()` is used alter the patterns of instantiations of parent classes.

Answer (score 0):

All classes in java directly or indirectly extends `java.lang.Object`.

Example if we write `class A`
Compiler will do something like `class A extends Object`.

Suppose

```
class A extends B {}
```

then this is interpreted as,

```
class B extends Object {}
class A extends B {}
```

It is said that a class cannot be initialized until the object class initialize its part. Hence it is the responsibility of the compiler to invoke the `Object` class constructor. The compiler does so by writing `super()` in your constructor as the first statement.So even if you did not create any default constructor compiler will create one and write `super()` to it.

In this case when you initialize the MyClass without any parameter it calls the default constructor which see `super()` in it so it calls the `Object` class constructor.
When you initialize the `MyClass` with the String parameter it calls the parameterized constructor which see super() in it so it calls the `Object` class constructor.

I hope I answered your query.